# Accidentally Used Topping Compound for Taping Drywall Joint. What To Do?

Tags: drywall, drywall-mud

I made a rookie mistake and accidentally used Topping Compound when I taped my newly-hung drywall.

To be clear: I used topping on the joint and then embedded the tape into it.

What should my next step(s) be?

Can I use all-purpose to go over the tape to help with adhesion? Or, should I just continue on and use Topping for 2nd and 3rd coats?

Answer (score 1):

Topping compound is softer and easier to sand than regular mud. If everything is dry and and secure you may be ok. If you want to remove it just get it wet and topping mud should release and can be scraped off. If you haven't done very many joints I would remove it because it is not as strong. If everything looks go ahead and top and sand with topping mud.